# Rails 3 serve assets in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, assets, production

Using Rails 3.2.2 and ruby 1.9.2 and I am not able to serve assets in production.  We are running on apache.  I've read some documentation and set :

```
config.serve_static_assets = true
config.assets.compile = true
```

in production.rb, and it doesn't seem to work.  What else can I try?  Or how can I get some debug info on where it IS looking.

Also, I went back to development, and went into assets/images and deleted .png files in order to intentionally break things in the development environment, but it didn't work, the images still show up.  There must be some pre-compiling of assets, but where do they get stored, and how would I clear that?  thanks

Comment: I had to run `rake assets:precompile` each time I deployed a new version of an app to a test Linux VM. Try running that and see if that helps.

Comment: are you deploying via capistrano?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually, if you have Apache in front of your rails server, you would not want your application to compile assets in production. You probably want to pre-compile assets and have Apache serve them.

Compiled assets are stored in public/assets by default.

How all this comes together depends on the particulars of your configuration, which you have not shared. I would recommend reading the rails guides on the asset pipeline:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

and in particular:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#in-production

It heven has some examples of how to configure Apache.

Comment: Yes, that is true, we do want to have apache serve them.  However, we are up against a demo deadline, where performance is not the priority, and I just wanted to get something working that is not runing locally.  Any help appreciated.  And thanks for the links.

Comment: Hmm... If you only need a demo, can you just server directly via thin or another rails server? That could be easier to acomplished. (See comment below by yfeldblum on enabling asset serving).

Answer (score 0):

In `config/application.rb`:

```
config.assets.enabled = true
```